# MySQL record deduplication

Tags: php, mysql, record-linkage

I'm just asking here what is the best approach to deduplicate your table in MySQL?

I have a sample table with the fields `id`,`name`, `lastname`, `user_no`, `birthday`,`percentage`, and then `parent_id`. What i want is to add a value at the `percentage` and `parent_id` fields based on which record is a duplicate and how similar they are.

I am just asking for an approach. Would it be efficient to check every field twice to check for a match? Or, is there another way?

Comment: If you cannot add any code, could you at least give an example?

Comment: how big is your database?  can all of the records be read into memory at the same time?  is your objective to deduplicate existing records, to prevent duplicate records in the future, or both?

Comment: You will also have to give some sort of explanation of how you decide how similar something is?  Does this mean some fields are the same, some different, similar names (whatever that would mean) etc.

Comment: @FKEinternet I'm assuming the database would have millions of records. just deduplicating the record would be it.

Comment: @NigelRen, for now, i'm using exact likeness. as in equal values. but I think i would use jaro winkler for this.

Comment: millions of records? I hope you've got some serious computing resources to apply to this problem, or lots of time...

Comment: @FKEinternet yup. That's why i'm asking for the most efficient way to check duplicating records. Do you think Iterating twice would be efficient?

Comment: Have you tried using `group by` to start and seeing if that gives you any insight into the extent of duplication?

Comment: @NigelRen nope. Here's a sample of my code asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197291/php-simple-deduplication-process . But this is just a dummy code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `id` field is unique to each record, and that the first record in the database with other similar ones is the `parent_id`

1. Read your first record, store its field values in local variables.
2. Read each successive record in the database.  If it has a `parent_id` value, go to the next record.
3. Compare the fields in the newly read record with the ones in the previously stored one.  If there is a sufficient match, update the newly read record's `parent_id` and `percentage` fields.
4. When you reach the end of the database but haven't compared all of the records ini it, read the next parent record (i.e., the second time, the second record in the database, assuming it doesn't have its `parent_id` field set), store its field values in the comparision variables, and repeat from step 2.

After reading the description of the problem with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197291/php-simple-deduplication-process), it looks like you'd want to change the selection criteria in step 4:  In order to find "better" matches, you wouldn't want to skip records with the `parent_id` field set, but rather use *every* record in the database, in succession, as a comparison source.  That also means you wouldn't want to skip records in step 2 with the `parent_id` already set - and you're going to read every record in the database ***n*** times, where *n* is its row number.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this later and give updates here.